# Wagtail 0.8.6 - submit for moderation - email notification to moderators group members

Tags: django, django-admin, django-signals, django-email, wagtail

I noticed that in the [docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v0.8.6/howto/settings.html?highlight=notifications#email-notifications) it's clearly mentioned that an email is sent when a page is submitted for moderators:

> ***Email Notifications***
>
> `WAGTAILADMIN_NOTIFICATION_FROM_EMAIL = ’wagtail@myhost.io’`
>
> Wagtail sends email notifications when content is submitted for moderation,
>   and when the content is accepted or rejected. This setting lets you
>   pick which email address these automatic notifications will come from.
>   If omitted, Django will fall back to using the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`
>   variable if set, and `webmaster@localhost` if not.

I tried locally, and an email is sent, but to the administrator users. 
Is it possible to change this behaviour and add more control over it? I need an email to be sent to the moderators users.
The only way that I noticed for now is to override the *save_revision* method in the ***Page*** model

Answer (score 0):

Email notifications are sent to all moderators (users with `publish` priviledges for the  given page managed through groups and group memberships). See [source code](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/blob/0845f1e1c1122e6ec4a9d75d488a23ed3d834554/wagtail/wagtailadmin/utils.py#L160) and [an owners comment on github](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/2173#issuecomment-177011259).

*Side note:*
As of Wagtail 1.3.1 there is currently a [bug sending notification emails](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/2173) which will be fixed in 1.4 released soon.